# Is template<typename T> the same as template<typename T, typename... Rest> if Rest... is empty?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, variadic-templates

I'm trying to create a "converting copy constructor" in a CRTP class like this:
template
struct Base;

```
template<typename Derived>
struct Base;

template<template<typename, typename...> class DerivedType, typename T, typename... Rest >
struct Base<DerivedType<T, Rest...>> {

    Base() = default;

    template<typename T2, typename... Rest2>
    Base(const Base<DerivedType<T2, Rest2...>>& other)  {
    }

};

template<typename T>
struct Child : Base<Child<T>> {

    using MyBase = Base<Child<T>>;

    Child() = default;    

    template<typename T2>
    Child(const Child<T2>& other) : MyBase(other) {}

};

int main() {

    Child<int> cti;
    Child<float> ctf = cti;

}
```

The code compiles with never gcc versions, but not with other compilers. They reject it because of too many template parameters:

```
<source>:11:21: error: too many template arguments for class template 'Child'

    Base(const Base<DerivedType<T2, Rest2...>>& other)  {
```

Clearly, the size of `Rest2...` is 0, so I'd expect it to match `Child<T2>`.

The workaround is to remove the template parameter `T2` from the definition of the Base constructor. However, I'd be curious which compiler is right here?

Live example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Lh3pa2).

Comment: There is a rule that makes programs ill-formed if the only valid (implicit or explicit) specializations of a variadic template must have an empty pack. But I can't say for sure yet whether that's the problem here.

Comment: Doesn't seem to compile with GCC either https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/R9U22W

Comment: @Ayxan: It does compile, see my link above. Your code is missing the primary declaration (probably a copy/paste issue). Ahh, sorry: It seems I forgot to include it in the example :/

Comment: Fixed the example...

Comment: Why not simply using the conversion operator?

Comment: Something like this: template<typename T2, typename... Rest2> operator Base<DerivedType<T, Rest...>>() {}

Comment: @MaxLanghof Intersting, I didn't know this rule. Not sure if this applies here, though, as we can easily fix this issue by adding a formal `typename...` to the definition of `Child`.

Comment: @florestan I think once you add `typename...` you don't have the issue of *must have an empty pack*. (since any pack would work)

Comment: @MFnx, yeah, that was actually the first thing I tried, but I need to be able to override the conversion in the derived classes. Which leads to an ambiguous conversion operator...

Comment: @appleapple, Hm, yeah, seems reasonable...

Comment: Could it be related to [P0522][http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0522r0.html]. There is only GCC that has implemented this C++17 feature

Comment: I fail to see why this leads to an ambiguous conversion operator. Wouldn't something like https://godbolt.org/z/SN2AYQ solve your problem?

Comment: This [simpler code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/XXJaz6) produce a very similar issue. If you remove `First` or `Rest...` from the argument list, it compiles. Same behavior as the code snippet of the op.

Comment: This is an example with both the conversion operator and the conversion copy constructor: https://godbolt.org/z/7ahRtK. Is this what you need?